# MySQL Query get total number of guests per company

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    c.name as company_name,
    sc.`date` as screening_date
from
    guests g
inner join 
    user_guest_group ugs on ugs.guest_id = g.id
inner join 
    companies c on c.id = g.company_id
inner join
    screening_date_guest sdg on sdg.guest_id = g.id
inner join
    screening_dates sc on sc.id = sdg.screening_date_id
where 
    sdg.attending = 1
and  
    screening_date_id = 1
group by
    first_name,
    last_name
```

Results:

```
Peter, M, Bell Media (ctv), 2015-05-18 00:00:00
Adam, D, Highway Entertainment, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
Todd, F., Multichoice, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
John, D, Talpa, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
Maria, F, UK TV, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
John, L, WBDTD, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
Albert, P, WBDTD, 2015-05-18 00:00:00
```

My query returns that resulset.

Now, I want to see another column with total guests per company.
In this case, we have 2 guests from WBTDT so it should say total_guest = 2

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have an `id` field in your `guests` table? that would be better to `GROUP BY g.id` then.

Comment: great point I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the count per company in a correlated subquery, so maybe this is what you want?

```
select 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    c.name as company_name,
    sc.date as screening_date,
    (
       select count(*) from guests
       inner join 
          user_guest_group  on user_guest_group.guest_id = guests.id
       inner join 
          companies  on companies.id = guests.company_id
       inner join
          screening_date_guest  on screening_date_guest.guest_id = guests.id
       inner join
          screening_dates  on screening_dates.id = screening_date_guest.screening_date_id
       where 
          screening_date_guest.attending = 1
       and  
          screening_date_id = 1 and company_id = c.id
    ) total_guests
from
    guests g
inner join 
    user_guest_group ugs on ugs.guest_id = g.id
inner join 
    companies c on c.id = g.company_id
inner join
    screening_date_guest sdg on sdg.guest_id = g.id
inner join
    screening_dates sc on sc.id = sdg.screening_date_id
where 
    sdg.attending = 1
and  
    screening_date_id = 1
group by
    first_name,
    last_name,
    c.id,
    c.name,
    sc.date
```

Comment: (select count(*) from guests where company_id = c.id) total_guests gave me numbers, but they were incorrect because my joins eliminated some guests..your query was giving to many guests per companies, even though the ones that dont have a screening_date for instance.

Comment: @vick Oh right. I was being lazy and didn't include the complete joins and where clauses in the subquery. Try it now please.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    c.name as company_name,
    sc.`date` as screening_date,
    count(g.id)
from
    guests g
inner join 
    user_guest_group ugs on ugs.guest_id = g.id
inner join 
    companies c on c.id = g.company_id
inner join
    screening_date_guest sdg on sdg.guest_id = g.id
inner join
    screening_dates sc on sc.id = sdg.screening_date_id
where 
    sdg.attending = 1
and  
    screening_date_id = 1
group by
    first_name,
    last_name,
    c.name
```

Comment: Almost there, that worked better.. but it does not give count per company.. it just gave me total guests ... 3 on all rows